# How to create an array from some array of objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I do programming in C# and I have an array of objects (Called `A`). Now I want to have another array which each cell contains an array of `A` (Called `B`). For example:

```
B=[A1,A2,A3];
```

Can someone direct me to the solution?

Comment: Two possibilities: List<List<A>> or A[][].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, an array of `A` objects is defined as:

```
A[]
```

Then, an array of... arrays of `A` objects is defined as:

```
A[][]
```

You can create it like this:

```
A[] a1 = new A[10];
A[] a2 = new A[20];
A[] a3 = new A[5];
A[][] b = new A[][] {a1, a2, a3};
```

You can index either as follows:

```
var value = b[2][3];
```

This will get the array at index 2, and element 3 of that array.